# PHPMailer: Как в тело письма встроить Youtube видео?

Tags: php, html

Нужно, чтобы человек открыл письмо и в нём посмотрел Youtube видео. HTML-код для встраивания видео от Youtube в теле письма не работает. Как, с помощью PHPMailer, в тело письма встроить Youtube видео для просмотра?

Comment: Вы пробовали через `<iframe>`?

Comment: Да, пробовал. HTML-код от Youtube как раз и использует <iframe>. Письмо открываю, ничего не отображается.

Comment: Добавьте код с Вашими попытками.

Comment: $resmail = '<div style="width: 400px; text-align: justify; margin: 0 auto;">
  <iframe width="320" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sFSioRyMLiA" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe><br><br>
 </div>';
$mail->Body = $resmail;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Никак.

Дело не в том, чем вы отправляете письмо, а в том, чем письма читают.

**Абсолютно все** известные мне email-клиенты не отображают `<iframe>` из соображений безопасности, да и спам-фильтры тоже относятся к таким трюкам крайне агрессивно.

Устоявшееся на практике решение: ссылка-картинка с обложкой видео, ведущая на страницу с проигрывателем. Опционально, с "наклееннной" на картинку кнопкой <kbd>▶</kbd>.